# Can editors of a Facebook Page request to join a group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-groups

I've recently learnt that you can join a Facebook group as a page yourself, which is great for me as that means I can interact as the page rather from my personal account. However, when joining a page that requires you to answer a question, I do not have the option to select the pages name.

A couple of points:

1. I'm only an Editor
2. The group admin has selected the right setting

[image]

Any ideas why I cannot join?

Answer (score 0):

From Facebook Help Center's [How do I join a Facebook group as myself or my Page?](https://www.facebook.com/help/103763583048280?helpref=related):

> Only Page admins can request to join a group.

So if you are only an editor of the page, you can't.